# Can't pass value from FirstVC to SecondVC using segue

Tags: swift, macos, segue, swift4, nsslider

I have two `ViewControllers` connected via `Show` segue. I need to pass `NSSlider`'s value from `ViewController` to `SecondViewCotroller`.

So, moving slider in `ViewController` a variable updates in `SecondViewController`.

How to update a value of `imagesQty` variable?

```
// FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: NSSlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var photosLabel: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func segueData(_ sender: NSSlider) {
        photosLabel.stringValue = String(slider.intValue) + " photos"
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC"), sender: slider)
    }

    func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: NSSlider?) {
        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueIdentifierForSecondVC" {
            if let secondViewController =
            segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController {
                secondViewController.imagesQty = slider.integerValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER

import Cocoa

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    var imagesQty = 30  

    override func viewWillAppear() {

    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.view.wantsLayer = true

    print("viewWillAppear – Qty:\(imagesQty)")

    //let arrayOfViews: [NSImageView] = [view01...view12]

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/ArrayOfElements")
    do {
        let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).reversed()
        let photos = fileURLs.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }

        for view in arrayOfViews {
            //"imagesQty" is here
            let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagesQty-1)))
            let image = NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: photos[i]))
            view.image = image
            view.imageScaling = .scaleNone
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the purpose and benefit of `NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier` is to create an extension to be able to avoid literals.

```
extension NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier {
    static let secondVC = NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier("SegueIdentifierForSecondVC")
}
```

Then you can write

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: .secondVC, sender: slider)
```

and

```
if segue.identifier! == .secondVC { ...
```

---

This error occurs because `imagesQty` is declared in `viewWillAppear` rather than on the top level of the class.

Change it to

```
class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    var imagesQty = 30 // Int is inferred

    // override func viewWillAppear() {
    //     super.viewWillAppear()
    // }
}
```

There is another mistake: The signature of `prepare(for segue` is wrong. It must be

```
func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

Comment: I fixed the code. I'm moving the slider and value isn't changed.
Maybe something else?

Comment: Is the action connected? Is the segue performed at all? Is the class of the second view controller set to `SecondViewController`?

Comment: Action is connected (from slider to controller, look at the picture). Class is SecondViewController. 
How to check if segue is performed?

Comment: Set breakpoints, insert `print` lines. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { } is set

Comment: print(segue) after secondViewController.imagesQty = Int(slider.intValue) is not working...

Comment: Does the identifier of the segue (in IB) match `SegueIdentifierForSecondVC`?

Comment: Yes, it's SegueIdentifierForSecondVC (I copied-pasted it, no errors)

Comment: Then connect the segue to the controller (rather than to the slider) and connect the slider to the IBAction.

Comment: What's supposed to happen in `viewWillAppear()`? You don't need to override the method if there is no custom code.

Comment: I connected the segue to the controller (it was connected to slider). Slider was connected to the IBAction, it's ok. I pasted print(imagesQty) in viewWillAppear() – no change! It prints 30.

Comment: If the segue is performed the code must work. Force unwrap `let secondViewController = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController` (remove `if` and the braces). If the code crashes there is a design error

Comment: Code is not crashed. I removed `if` and `{ }`

Comment: viewDidLoad – Qty:30
<NSStoryboardSegue:0x600000049a50 identifier='SegueIdentifierForSecondVC', source='<Pixie.ViewController: 0x6000001808f0>', destination='<NSWindowController: 0x6100000878a0>'>
viewWillAppear – Qty:30
viewDidAppear – Qty:30

Comment: It was in Output area.

Comment: Does the slider send 30? Set `imagesQty` to `0` or a negative value. Once again, the code is correct and must work.

Comment: Regarding the issue the code in your answer is irrelevant. Please debug the code. Is `prepare(for segue` called? Is the line `secondViewController.imagesQty = Int(slider.intValue)` reached? By the way `intValue` returns `Int`, this is another redundant initializer. Again, please don't misuse answers for more information. Edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can‘t change the value because the var is defined in the function and not in the class.

Make your var a class property and it should work.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var imagesQty: Int = 30

...

}
```